# NestJS using Jest test async functions within async functions

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to write a test for my service, and everything is working (the service, the tests so far) but I am not able to verify a function is called, and this is failing.  However, the code coverage output from the test indicates the line is being executed, and if I run the code itself, it does delete the data.

I have tried to copy just the relevant part of the service processing to illustrate my issue.  My service maintains holiday dates from an external service.  This will remove bad entries, as well as add new holiday date records moving forward per year. I have trimmed this down to just the functions I am having the issue with.

```
export class UpdateService {
    constructor(
        private readonly HolidayDateDataService_: HolidayDatesService,
    ) {
        this.RemoveInvalidHolidayDateEntriesForAYear(Year);
    }

    async RemoveInvalidHolidayDateEntriesForAYear(Year: number): Promise<void> {
        let ExistingHolidayDates: Array<HolidayDatesResponseDTO>;

        try {
            ExistingHolidayDates = await this.HolidayDateDataService_.GetAllRecordsByYear(Year); // From external API
        } catch (Exception) {
            return;
        }

        ExistingHolidayDates.forEach( async (OneDateEntry: HolidayDatesResponseDTO) => {
            const HolidayIdIsActive: boolean = await this.ValidateHolidayIdActive_(OneDateEntry.HolidayId); // Validates Entry should be maintained.  
            if (! HolidayIdIsActive) {
                await this.DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_(OneDateEntry);
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    async DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_(HolidayDateData: HolidayDatesResponseDTO): Promise<void> {
        console.log('Start DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_');
        try {
            console.log('Start HolidayDateDataService');
            await this.HolidayDateDataService_.Delete(
                new HolidayDatesEntity(HolidayDateData.HolidayId, HolidayDateData.Name, HolidayDateData.Year),
                HolidayDateData.Key_
            );
            console.log('End HolidayDateDataService');
        } catch (Exception) {
            ; // Do nothing, try the next one
        }
        console.log('End DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_');
        return;
    }

    async ValidateHolidayIdActive_(HolidayId: string): Promise<boolean> {
        console.log('Start ValidateHolidayIdActive_');
        try {
            console.log('Start HolidayIdDateService');

            const HolidayIdData: HolidayIdsResponseDTO = await this.HolidayIdDataService_.GetOne(HolidayId);

            console.log('End HolidayIdDateService');
            if (HolidayIdData && HolidayIdData.Active) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            ; // Do nothing as the method ends with a return false
        }
        console.log('End ValidateHolidayIdActive_');
        return false;
    }
}
```

As I said, all of this works.  However, I am trying to test and verify that the delete is called.

```
describe('UpdateService', () => {
    let service: UpdateService;
    let HolidayIdsTestService: HolidayIdsService;
    let HolidayDatesTestService: HolidayDatesService;

    const HolidayRecords: Array<HolidaysApi> = new Array<HolidaysApi>(
        { id: 31, name: 'Christmas Day', observedDate: '2022-12-27' } as HolidaysApi,
        { id: 32, name: 'Boxing Day', observedDate: '2022-12-28' } as HolidaysApi,
    );


    beforeEach(async () => {
        const mockHolidayIdsService = {
            provide: HolidayIdsService,
            useValue: {
                GetOne: jest.fn(),
            },
        };

        const mockHolidayDatesService = {
            provide: HolidayDatesService,
            useFactory: () => ({
                Delete: jest.fn(),
                GetAllRecordsByYear: jest.fn(),
            }),
        };

        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                UpdateService,
                mockHolidayDatesService,
                mockHolidayIdsService,
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<UpdateService>(UpdateService);
        HolidayIdsTestService = module.get<HolidayIdsService>(HolidayIdsService);
        HolidayDatesTestService = module.get<HolidayDatesService>(HolidayDatesService);
    });

    it('should delete HolidayDate records if ValidateHolidayIdActive_ returns false', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(HolidayDatesTestService, GetAllRecordsByYear').mockResolvedValue(HolidayDateRecords);
    jest.spyOn(HolidayIdsTestService, 'GetOne').mockResolvedValue(new HolidayIdsResponseDTO('Fake_Holiday_Id', false, 31, 'Christmas Day'));
    jest.spyOn(HolidayDatesTestService, 'Delete').mockResolvedValue();

    await service.RemoveInvalidHolidayDateEntriesForAYear(2022);
    expect(HolidayIdsTestService.GetOne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(HolidayDatesTestService.Delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
});
```

The problem in my tests, is that the last expect fails:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

  532 |             await service.RemoveInvalidHolidayDateEntriesForAYear(2022);
  533 |             expect(HolidayIdsTestService.GetOne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
> 534 |             expect(HolidayDatesTestService.Delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
      |                                                    ^
```

The problem I am having is the `ValidateHolidayIdActive_` is called 2 times (which uses the HoldiayIdsTestService internally, which is mocked), which I expect, and as it was mocked to return a False status, the `DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_` should be called 2 times as well.  However, both `.toHaveBeenCalled()` and `.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)` fail when validating the internal service is called, which is again mocked.

However, with my console.log() calls in the code, I can see that the modules are called in the proper orde, and everything is started, and then completes up the chain.

Record #1

```
console.log Start ValidateHolidayIdActive_
console.log Start HolidayIdDateService
console.log Start ValidateHolidayIdActive_
console.log Start HolidayIdDateService

console.log End HolidayIdDateService
console.log End ValidateHolidayIdActive_
console.log End HolidayIdDateService
console.log End ValidateHolidayIdActive_
```

Record #2

```
console.log   Start DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_
console.log   Start HolidayDateDataService
console.log   Start DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_
console.log   Start HolidayDateDataService

console.log   End HolidayDateDataService
console.log   End DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_
console.log   End HolidayDateDataService
console.log   End DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_
```

It does appear to call and finish correctly.  However, the one function is spied as working, and the other is not.  I cannot understand my error.

Any help is appreciated, as it should be a simple mistake, but is completely frustrating me, and I cannot seem to find it.  I had the functionality a lot more together in one function originally, and have broken it out like this to test each function (which works with the same style of mocks).

Answer (score 0):

My issue has to do with the processing I am doing.  await/async cannot run loops that have callbacks, such as forEach().  Use the for..of format, will correct the errors I am encountering.  It takes some restructing of the code I have written, but it does correct the issue.

```
...
ExistingHolidayDates.forEach( async (OneDateEntry: HolidayDatesResponseDTO) => {
    const HolidayIdIsActive: boolean = await 
    this.ValidateHolidayIdActive_(OneDateEntry.HolidayId); // Validates Entry should be maintained.  
    if (! HolidayIdIsActive) {
        await this.DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_(OneDateEntry);
        }
    });
});
```

Change the handling to not be a callback with forEach, but to be a for..of instead:

```
for (OneDateEntry of ExistingHolidayDates) => {
    const HolidayIdIsActive: boolean = await 
    this.ValidateHolidayIdActive_(OneDateEntry.HolidayId); // Validates Entry should be maintained.  
    if (! HolidayIdIsActive) {
        await this.DeleteOneHolidayDateRecord_(OneDateEntry);
        }
    });
});
```

This will allow the proper processing.